# Why error "TypeError: set_window_position() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'" appears despite the argument y is present?

Tags: python, selenium

Anyone has an idea why the error appears despite the argument is present? :)
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")

listOfLinks = open("test.txt", "r")
#  open test page in the browser
browser: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Valeriia\\PycharmProjects\\selen\\chromedriver.exe', options=opt)
page = browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')
time.sleep(5)
browser.set_window_position({'x': -4, 'y': -1})
browser.set_window_size({'width': 1448, 'height': 1085})
```

Comment: try this: `browser.set_window_position( -4,  -1)`. don't send parameters as dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide a `dict` as a single parameter however the function requires 2 (x and y).

Try instead:

```
browser.set_window_position(**{'x': -4, 'y': -1})
```

or:

```
browser.set_window_position(x=-4, y=-1)
```

or:

```
browser.set_window_position(-4, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're providing the arguments to [browser.set_window_position](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_position) in a dictionary, but it is expecting the result in a different format. Both of these should work:

```
browser.set_window_position(x=-4, y=-1)
```

or

```
browser.set_window_position(-4, -1)
```

Alternatively, if you store the dictionary somewhere else and pass it in, you can use the double-asterisk syntax to unpack it as a set of keyword arguments:

```
coordinates = {'x':-4, 'y':-1}
browser.set_window_position(**coordinates)
```